# Ember Addon Component with attribute Integration fails ember-beta and canary scenarios

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-addons

I'm looking for some help in troubleshooting some very basic ember addon component integration tests and am hoping someone may have an idea where to look to get this sorted out.  The tests are included below:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('my-comp', {
    integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
    this.render(hbs`{{my-comp}}`);
    assert.ok(this.$());
});

test('it renders with attribute', function(assert) {
    this.render(hbs`{{my-comp title="hi"}}`);
    assert.ok(this.$());
});

test('it renders with attribute (again)', function(assert) {
    this.set('componentTitle', 'hello');
    this.render(hbs`{{my-comp title=componentTitle}}`);
    assert.ok(this.$());
});
```

The addon was created using ember blueprints and all 3 tests pass in the following ember-try scenarios:

- default, using: version: 1.13.8
- ember-release, using: ember 2.2.0

Only the tests that have components with attributes fail in the following scenarios:

- ember-beta, using: ember 2.3.0-beta.1
- ember-canary, using: ember 2.4.0-canary+d25e0d77

The error reported for both failing scenarios is the same:

```
not ok 10 PhantomJS 2.0 - component:my-comp: it renders with attribute
---
    actual: >
        null
    message: >
        Died on test #1     at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1989:15)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/dummy.js:486:19
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:34
            at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30:21)
            at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:148:15)
            at require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29:16)
            at loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21:25)
            at load (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40:35)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6822:20: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'my-comp' could not be found
    Log: |
...
not ok 11 PhantomJS 2.0 - component:my-comp: it renders with attribute (again)
---
    actual: >
        null
    message: >
        Died on test #1     at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1989:15)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/dummy.js:527:19
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:34
            at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30:21)
            at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:148:15)
            at require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29:16)
            at loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21:25)
            at load (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40:35)
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6822:20: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'my-comp' could not be found
    Log: |
...
```

My environment is as follows:

- ember/cli: 1.13.8
- PhantomJS 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this one was to upgrade ember-qunit from "0.4.9" to "0.4.16".

Comment: Thanks for indicating the fix!